# How to get public ip address for virtual-machine using Azure CLI command

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I want to get public IP address for a specific virtual machine in Azure bash command line, I have used this command so far but it returns network interface information:

```
az vm list-ip-addresses -g dev-rg -n dev-vm
```

returned value:

```
[
  {
    "virtualMachine": {
      "name": "dev-vm",
      "network": {
        "privateIpAddresses": [
          "10.0.0.5"
        ],
        "publicIpAddresses": [
          {
            "id": "/subscriptions/*********/resourceGroups/dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/dev-vmPublicIP",
            "ipAddress": "52.142.***.***",
            "ipAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
            "name": "dev-vmPublicIP",
            "resourceGroup": "dev-rg"
          }
        ]
      },
      "resourceGroup": "dev-rg"
    }
  }
]
```

I only need the IP address value which should be something like this: 52.142.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can just use the CLI command `az vm show -d -g resourceGroupName -n vmName --query publicIps -o tsv` to output the public IP.

It just shows like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could also continue with your initial idea (key points are the `--query` and `--output` parameters):

```
az vm list-ip-addresses --resource-group dev-rg --name dev-vm --query "[].virtualMachine.network.publicIpAddresses[0].ipAddress" --output tsv
```

As the [documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_show-optional-parameters), using `az vm show --show-details` could be slow.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get public IPs for many machine you can also use the `az network public-ip`:

```
az network public-ip list -o table
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short Command**

```
az vm list-ip-addresses -n SampleVM -o table
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/manage-virtual-machines-with-azure-cli/6-querying-vms