# Powershell - Select only one value from -out table

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I need to select only one value from the out-table.

The code is:

```
az vm list-ip-addresses --name VMname --resource-group GroupName --out table
```

I get the result as below

```
VirtualMachine    PublicIPAddresses    PrivateIPAddresses
----------------  -------------------  --------------------
VMName            XX.XX.XX.XX          XX.XX.XX.XX
```

I want to select only the `PublicIPAddresses` value and extract it to csv.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Output format option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli) **`--output table`** (`-o table`) is **meant for *human-friendly* (tabular) display rather than for *programmatic processing***.

It's **better to use an output format based on *structured text*, such as JSON**.
Indeed, JSON is the *default* output format, so you can simply *omit* your `--out table` argument and use [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) to parse the output and extract the values of interest:

```bash
# Outputs all public IP addresses contained in the JSON response.
# Since you're targeting only a *single* VM, the address(es) all refer to that VM.
$ip =
  (
   az vm list-ip-addresses --name VMname --resource-group GroupName |
     ConvertFrom-Json
  ).virtualMachine.network.publicIpAddresses.ipaddress
```

The structure of the JSON data returned is assumed to be the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54980260/45375).

---

Note that you can **streamline** the operation by using the `--query` parameter to perform a [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) query *at the source*, so that only the values of interest are directly returned:

```bash
$ip =
  (az vm list-ip-addresses --query '[].virtualMachine.network.publicIpAddresses[].ipAddress' --name VMname --resource-group GroupName |
    ConvertFrom-Json)
```

Note:

- You could simplify this further by using `--output tsv`, in which case you don't need the `ConvertFrom-Json` call - see below.

---

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980320/45375), the following **shorter alternative** that uses the [`az vm show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-show) sub-command - rather than [`az vm list-ip-addresses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-list-ip-addresses) - works too:

```bash
$ip = 
  az vm show --show-details --resource-group --name vmName --query publicIps --output tsv
```

Note:

- The above uses a *different* structured text format, TSV (tab-separated values), with `--output tsv`, which in this simple case obviates the need for post-processing on the PowerShell side:

  - The query returns one or more *string* values only, which in TSV format are output as-is, and, if there is more than one string, each on its own line. PowerShell captures this as either a single string or as an array of strings.

---

##### Extracting public IPs for *multiple* VMs (all VMs in a resource group):

```bash
# Returns the names and public IP addresses for all VMs in the
# given resource group, as [pscustomobject] instances with
# .name and .publicIds properties (the latter being an array).
$objects =
  az vm list-ip-addresses --query '[].virtualMachine.{ name: name, publicIps: network.publicIpAddresses[].ipAddress }' --resource-group GroupName |
    ConvertFrom-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the option **-d** which will pick up the default defined public IP address:

```
publicIp='az vm show -g group1 -n vm1 -d --query publicIps -o tsv'
```